# Android: How to solve the emulator error while installing it on ec2 instance?

Tags: android, amazon-ec2, android-emulator

i am trying to run following command

```
   $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "emulator"
```

getting error Warning: Failed to find package emulator

trying to install android SDK viva command line 
 I did install a `build tool, platform tool`. but when I am trying to install emulator its shows no package available. When I run `/sdkmanager --list` it's not showing emulator in Available Packages. Does the emulator depend upon CPU n OS ?

Comment: For using emulator simply go to AVD manager of AS and download emulator you want.

Comment: i am trying to install it on ec2 instance

Comment: You have downloaded emulator folder in your SDK?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/atyachin/cf1690085173e1fabc07b9acc7af3de6 following this

Comment: /opt/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "emulator"
 it giving error

Comment: What do you mean? ec2 instance

Comment: trying it on ci/cd

Comment: in my mac emulator is in /tools folder, do emulator exist in /tools/bin folder ?

Comment: ./sdkmanager --list  is not showing emulator in available packages   that mean its not supported ?

Comment: Same issue on Raspian/RPi 4. When I ran the same command (`sdkmanager emulator`) on my Windows machine it succeeded. Perhaps it is some sort of OS/Hardware issue. (also, similar issue for referenceability: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63332696/11411686)

Comment: Did someone could solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I can not install build-tools on an infrequent Ubuntu through cmdline-tools, I soluted by a special way, steps as follows:

1.Run **./sdkmanager "emulator"** on another common Ubuntu which support.

2.Then a folder named **emulator** will be created at the sdk root path.

3.Copy this **emulator folder** to the previous Ubuntu at the same path.

4.Now, I can install build-tools through **./sdkmananger "build-tools;29.0.3"** .