# Failed to find package emulator Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-emulator, avd-manager

I was trying to install Android studio on Linux. But getting this error while creating **AVD and install SDK build tools**.

Whenever I try to do any of the two it gives errors:

> Failed to find package emulator (while creating AVD) or dependent
> package with key emulator not found(while installing SDK build Tools.

Tried to look for a solution but failed, any help?

Ps: `./sdkmanager channel=3` emulator doesn't work.

[image: Heres how it looks]

Comment: What operating system/hardware are you using? I had the same issue on Raspian/RPi-4 and apparently, someone else experienced it with an EC2 (https://stackoverflow.com/q/61065034/11411686).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by installing Android Studio and using the emulator that comes with. On Windows it's found in `Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator`